# Adding home icon to the tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

I want to implement a bar at the bottom of the screen with the **home button** - exactly like in Instagram or Messanger apps. I was trying to use a tab bar (https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/tab-bars/)

And I would like to utilize system home icon for the tab bar button/item (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationshortcuticontype/1623374-home)

Is there any simple and straight forward way to set this home icon for the tab bar item?
Some icons can be selected directly from the list in the button/item properties in Xcode, but this home icon is not among them.
I also saved the png from the link above, resized it to 30x30 and added as a picture for the button/item, but it's just showing a grey rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Well, the way xcode handles this situation is pure stupidity. And there is no shame in pointing it out. I guess there are some developers who fall in love with their favourite company/technology. Then they get personally offended by comments like that. Feel free to keep voting me down.

Comment: Home icon is the most standard navigation element - already familiar to the milions of users from apps like Messenger, Instagram, Google translator and many, many more on iOS. At the same time Apple excludes home icon from the list of icons available by default for it navigation bars, including icons no one really use. Your problem, as a developer community working with this technology, is that you guys say - "this is just the way it is, we need to go with it, ranting will only get you less help".

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the current result. Also, are you sure the image name is spelled correctly?

Comment: I'll add the screenshots later today, I'm not currently on my mac, trying to make some progress on my app, while I can't work on it directly at the moment. I think Matic may be right in his answer that the picture is not showing up ok, because I need to process this png further, apply transparent background, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple may or may not provide you with some images. In general no one uses stock images but provide their own. You should do the same.

So "Adding home icon to the tab bar" is pretty much the same as for any other tab bar item. You can add your image and/or text that represents your "home" button. Some images may already be at your disposal but others must be made/bought/stolen by you.

The image you use in tab bar item is only used as a mask and not as an explicit image. What that means is that only alpha component of the image will be taken. In your case you have a black icon on white background which from alpha perspective means you have a rectangle. You will need to remove the white background and make it transparent or use another image that already has these properties.

I am not sure for tab bar but you might also try to open your assets, select your image and then in options on the right find "Render as" and set it to "Original image". Even if this will work the results will not be as you desire (at least in most cases) due to a white background on the image.

In general this option is used to set it to "template" which means whenever you use this image on your components such as `UIImageView` it will use it's tint color and image alpha component instead of the actual colors from the image. It is a very useful tool but again I am not sure it will work on tab bar item.

You should stop wondering if Xcode is designed to be overcomplicated. Putting aside numerous amount of bugs (and there is really a lot of them) and it being slow (it really used to be faster) it is designed very nicely. But tab bar view controller is extremely high level component. If you don't like it the way it is then simply create your own. All you need is a bottom view with your `N` buttons which may be shaped any way you can possibly imagine and a container view on which you set a new view controller when one of those buttons is pressed.

Comment: Many thanks, you are 100% percent correct! Setting transparent background in the png did the trick. As for setting "Render as" to "Original image", it did make the picture appear on the tab bar, but as you said in this case white background is shown, if not removed.